# Passing file contents as an array to the loop

Tags: arrays, file, loops, powershell

I am trying to pass file content as an array to a loop as below. I am unable to get it to work. Is it possible using PowerShell ?

`$cdnoutputFile` file has this data: `'1.1.1.1', '1.2.3.4', '2.2.2.2'`

```bsh
$getCDNoutputFile = Get-Content $cdnoutputFile
$pingAddress = @($getCDNoutputFile)

foreach ($ip in $pingAddress) {
    $ping = ping $ip
    $ping | Out-File $resultFile -Append
}
```

Comment: Your code should already do that, provided your input file has each IP address in a separate line. If your input data has the addresses as a comma-separated string in a single line I'd suggest you fix your input data.

Comment: Does your file have one IP address per line, or one line with several comma-separated IP addresses? Your question indicates the latter, but several comments to answers here make me think it may be the former.

Comment: @Joel, The suggested code is working. Actually, I was working on a VM and for some reason it was behaving properly. I renounced it and spun a new VM with Windows 7 and Windows 8, both are working good. No issues. Believe the issue is with VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below steps will help you

```
   $getCDNoutputFile = Get-Content $cdnoutputFile

#Finitializing
    $getCDNoutputFile="'1.1.1.1', '1.2.3.4', '2.2.2.2'";

    $tmp=$getCDNoutputFile -split ","

    foreach ($ip in $tmp){
    $ip=($ip -replace "'","").Trim(" ");
    $ping = ping $ip
    $ping | Out-File $resultFile -Append
    }
```

However, instead of using window cmd's classic PING command, use of powershell's Test-Connection is wise choice, If it suits your requirement

Edit:

test.txt contains
'1.1.1.1', '1.2.3.4', '2.2.2.2'

```
$getCDNoutputFile = Get-Content test.txt
$resultFile="ping.txt"
    $tmp=$getCDNoutputFile -split ",";

    foreach ($ip in $tmp){
    $ip=($ip -replace "'","").Trim(" ");
    $ping = ping $ip
    $ping | Out-File $resultFile -Append
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this method, program takes only first item and it does not iterate to next item. The program does not proceed after taking and executing first argument.

Comment: That doesnt look like the case. I tried the edited code and it is iterating properly

Comment: Please check and let me know if you are getting any error or you are reading the file properly(echoing the file output should help)

Comment: true, there is no issue with the suggested code, best guess is my VM for the issue. I had renounced it and spun up two new VMs with Win 7 and 8. Both are working good with the code. Truly, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment from Ansgar the simplest solution would be to edit your input file to a single IP per line, however if that is not possible then you could instead do:

```
$pingAddress = ($getCDNoutputFile -split ",") -replace "'"
```

The split creates an array of IP Addressea and the replace removes the single quotes surrounding them (by defining no second variable in the replace I believe it will remove the character by default).

Comment: There's no `-trim` operator. `$getCDNoutputFile -split ',' |ForEach-Object Trim " '"`

Comment: Oh thanks. Thought I had used it that way in the past. Perhaps Replace is better then.

Comment: @Mark - I have tried using -replace, the program is only taking the first argument and does not move to the next item at all. The program stalls after running the first argument.

Comment: @Mathias - I have tried using ForEach-Object, the program is only taking the first argument and does not move to the next item at all. The program stalls after running the first argument.

Comment: @Mark, and Mathias, The suggested code is working. I was working on a Windows 7 VM and for some reason it was behaving properly maybe thinking Windows Updates. I renounced it and spun a new VM with Windows 7 and Windows 8, code is working good on both. No issues. Believe the issue is with VM.